# Correct value is not coming on UI from XML in c#

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, string, properties

I have one xml file where I have one entry like this:

```
<Item name="ID" value="001" />
char []t_id = new char[25];
```

I have property on business logic side :

```
 public char[] XID
    {
        get { return this.t_id; }
        set { this.t_id = value; }
    }
```

Property on UI side which bind to textBox:

```
public string YID
    {
        get
        {
            char[] value = this.Obj.XID;
            return new string(value);
        }
        set
        {
            this.Obj.XID = value.ToCharArray();
        }
    }
```

During XMl Parsing Getting default value of ID like this :

```
case "ID":
this.XID = node.Value.ToCharArray();
break;
```

Problem is that when I'm launching My application I'm getting system.char[] in place of value 001.
Please tell me where I have done mistake, why I'm not getting correct value.

Comment: Well what's the relation between `pid` and `t_id`? You've just shown us snippets, but we don't know how they interrelate. It would really help if you could provide a short but *complete* example demonstrating the problem...

Comment: I have char array of length 25 for which I have created property XID on business logic side this property is called through YID property. which Is UI proerty bind to textbox text property.

Comment: That doesn't really help us nearly as much as a short but complete example... it's entirely possible that the problem is in code you haven't shown us. If you can help us reproduce it, we can help you fix it...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to use the [`INotifyPropertyChanged` Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) to update the `YID` property when the `XID` property changes. Try something like this:

```
public char[] XID
{
    get { return this.t_id; }
    set { this.t_id = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("YID"); }
}
```

Also, if you're seeing `system.char[]` instead of the actual `string`, then that makes me think that you are displaying the `XID` property instead of the `YID` property. Try something like this instead:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding YID}" />
```